# Can you pass a resource into the parameters of a query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So i have a statement:

```
 $r = mysql_query("Select type from boats where type like '%speed%'");
```

can I then apply the constructed resource to another query?

```
 $r2 = mysql_query("select * from assets where type in ".$r);
```

I am trying to do something similar to

```
 select * from assets where type in (select type from boats where type like '%speed%')
```

Comment: i dont even know why this was downvoted....  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

But you could combine the sql.

```
$sql = "Select type from boats where type like '%speed%'";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
$r2 = mysql_query("select * from assets where type in ($sql)");
```

Or instead of subquery, you could use a join.

```
$r2 = mysql_query("select a.* from assets a 
                   join boats b on a.type = b.type and b.type like '%speed%'");
```

Comment: THank you @xdazz, i think that is a good answer to me.  I was trying to figure that out.  I just didnt like the idea of querying it a second time, as well, it is redundant.  This will have to do.